# How to call a dll method ( which is having dll reference of other custom code ) from a Windows Service in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, dll, service

I have created a windows service in C#. I'm able to install and run service.

But when I add my code dll file into the service and try to call the my method from onStart(), I'm getting no result and service shutdowns.

I have code structure like this :

MyCode.dll have 3 other dll refrenced. 
I have to call MyCode.dll method from Windows Service onStart() ( or I will create delegates to watch on file directory and then call my method )

Windows Service   <==    MyCode.dll    <==   a.dll , b.dll , c.dll

Details :
My windows service will watch on directory for File change. and I want to call my Method in another dll to execute the file based on type of change.
or If there is way by which windows service can notify my c# code about file directory change ?

```
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
       // Demo1() is a method I have to call.
       // I have added a dll reference for this.
        MyProgram.Demo1();

        base.OnStart(args);

    }
```

I have tried to call method from from both onStart() and through delegates also
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A Windows service is a perfectly ordinary process from the kernel's point of view.  DLL handling isn't any different to any other executable - well, unless you're trying to load the DLL from the current directory, I suppose.  Process Monitor (available from the MS web site) might be useful if the DLL isn't loading at all; otherwise you might need to use a debugger.

Comment: Thanks @Harry, Actually issue was with my code, it was throwing an File exception.